# How to retrieve page data as input and give a custom defined Output to the user?

Tags: python, django

I have created a translator, it's not a language translator, it only changes type of Alphabet from right to left to right to left style (Like Hebrew or Arabic to a Latin like typography).

So now I keep trying to imagine on how to create a web app that takes a URL like Google Translator and give back the link to the user with the translated content!

Any idea? Approach? Somewhere to start?
I'm using Python + Django =  Lots of Regex stuff, so feel free to hit me with confusing suggestions as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal version is just a view which:

- gets an input URL parameter from its own URL,
- fetches the input URL,
- applies transformations,
- return the transformed content to the client.

Thats should be pretty simple in Django, something among the lines of:

```
import urllib2
from django.views.generic import View

class SimpleProxy(View):
    def get(self, request, source_url, *args, **kwargs):
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        body = response.read()
        # Update body here
        return HttpResponse(body, status=response.getcode(),
            content_type=response.headers['content-type'])
```

You may want to take a look at [Django HTTP Proxy](http://httpproxy.yvandermeer.net/) or other similar solutions, which do basically the same thing, albeit with a different URL handling scheme as they use fixed target URLs.

Then depending on your needs you might want do develop more advanced features, e.g.:

- Copy request headers from the client to the `urllib2` request, so that the source site receives the proper headers.
- Rewrite URLs in the response to the client so that they will also point to your service (that should be quite easy for `href`, `src` and `action` tags, less so inside JavaScript).
- Support POST requests.

Comment: Thanks! This awesome! I found out about Beautiful Soup Library, thanks this is great again, but now am actually stuck at where I want to put back the HTML page together with the new EDIT and show it back to the User!